# swift iOS difference between : and ()

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

As a swift newbie I wonder what the difference between:

```
var img : UIImageView
var img = UIImageView()
```

I see them used a lot in the same situation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the first example `var img: UIImageView` creates a variable the WILL be of type UIImageView, once something is assigned to it.  This line itself does not initialize or create a new instance and its not assigned to anything.

the second example is actually creating a new instance of [UIImageView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/index.html) assigned to the variable that is called img.  It infers from the instance create of UIImageView that it will a variable of type UIImageView so no need to type it, its redundant

Answer (score 1):

The first one is a variable declaration and there you set the type of the variable, not a value.

The second line sets a new instance of the class.

Since swift is **strong typed** everything must have a type, so if you want to store something in a var you need to set the type of the var first, therefore the first line, on the second one is classic instantiation of the variables.